# Is there any way to differentiate between iTunes Match and DRMed tracks on iOS 5?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, drm, mpmediaitem, avasset

For a given MPMediaItem representing a track in an iOS5 user's music library, how can we determine if a track is:

- an iTunes Match track that has not been downloaded from iCloud

vs.

- a DRMed track

?

In both cases the NSURL returned by MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL is nil. Therefore instantiating an AVAsset to check the exportable flag is not a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that it depends on the version of iOS you use. I think prior to maybe 4.3, an asset returning `nil` meant simply that the item was DRMed and you didn't have access to it. However, in current versions (5), nil means it's iCloud only. Maybe you have tracks that you think are just DRMed but are in fact iCloud stored songs. On the current app I'm working on, I originally didn't account for iCloud tracks at all (as I was targeting the app for prior versions of iOS) and so I was getting crashes depending on who's device I used. To solve the issue and test for iCloud/DRM I use:

```
AVURLAsset* asset;
NSURL* realAssetUrl = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
if(!realAssetUrl){
    //track is iCloud
}

asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:realAssetUrl options:nil];
if(asset == nil || asset.hasProtectedContent){
    //asset is DRMed such that it cannot be played back.
            //most apps can stop here but I need to be able to export the song

}
if (!asset.exportable || !asset.readable){
    //the asset cannot be exported and thus cannot be cached to a file
            //the current app directory and cannot be transferred over network
            //if asset passed earlier check, can still be used for local playback
}
[asset release];
```

That seems to work fine for me, but you also imply you were headed down the same path, already, so I'm not sure how much help that'll be to you. However, good luck with your project and I hope you find the answer you're looking for!

Comment: I can say definitely that on iOS 5, the asset URL is nil in both the iCloud and DRM cases. Therefore your solution (which is what I tried as well) doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: I think we're having very different experiences using the OS. Let me know it you find/found a solution, I'd be thankful to hear it.